# Dauernd vs andauernd

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *dauernd* und *andauernd*?

Bei Leo.org bedeuten die beiden *continous* und *lasting*. Also wenn ich schreibe:

> Ich stelle meinem Freund **dauernd** Fragen zur deutschen Grammatik

Ist es ähnlich wie :

> Ich stelle meinem Freund **andauernd** Fragen zur deutschen Grammatik?

Danke!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das bedeutet in diesem Fall (als Adverb) beides ziemlich genau dasselbe.

Für mich klingt in "andauernd" ein bisschen mehr Genervtheit mit, aber ich glaube, dass das von Mensch zu Mensch verschieden ist und dabei kommt es auch mehr auf die Betonung an als auf das Wort an sich.

Eine weitere Alternative zu "dauernd" und "andauernd" ist auch "ständig". Das bedeutet zwar eigentlich eher, dass etwas in einer Zeitperiode öfter passiert, wird aber in solchen Zusammenhängen oft synonym benutzt.

Comment: Und weiter? Wie zum Beispiel "Ich stelle meinem Freund weiter Fragen zur deutschen Sprache". Ist das dasselbe wie die beiden oder so?

Comment: Nein, weiter ist etwas anders. Dauernd und andauernd implizieren, dass man das oft macht. Weiter oder weiterhin heißen einfach nur, dass man nicht damit aufhört, es kann aber sein, dass man nur einmal im Jahr eine Frage stellt, das aber weiterhin tun wird. Auch ist mit weiter/weiterhin der Blick auf die Zukunft gerichtet, während dauernd sich eher auf die Gegenwart bezieht. Da es nicht das gleiche bedeutet, kann man auch kombinieren: "Ich stelle meinem Freund weiter dauernd Fragen." Also auch in Zukunft, und oft.

Comment: Danke sehr für die Erklärung. Ich benutze immer dauernd "weiter" um "to keep doing something" zu sagen.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt aber schon Differenzen. z.B.:

*Die immer noch andauernde Belastung durch die Kriegsfolgen*

Hier kann man IMHO andauernd nicht durch dauernd ersetzen.
Der Sinn des obigen Satzes ist, daß die Belastung noch da ist, aber man hofft, daß sie irgendwann endet. Hier ist *immer noch dauernde* meiner Meinung nach nicht ok.

Comment: Aber das ist *dauernd* und *andauernd* als Adjektiv. Da hast du recht. In der Frage werden sie aber als Adverb verwendet und in dieser Verwendung ist mir kein Beispiel eingefallen, wo die Bedeutung unterschiedlich wäre. Ich finde *dauernd* als Adjektiv auch irgendwie seltsam; Duden listet zwar den Beispielsatz "Er hat hier seinen dauernden Wohnsitz.", aber da würde *ständig* meiner Meinung nach deutlich natürlicher klingen.

Comment: @filaltra ich habe mich auf die ursprüngliche Frage bezogen, nicht auf das dann folgende Bespiel.